# How to contraint the bottom edge and top edge of a view to another view in auto layout ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to place a circular imageview on top of another imageview something like in the picture. Does anyone know how i can achieve it.

[image: Circular imageview on top of imageview]

Comment: Set equal bottoms with a constant offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard, you can do it by setting circular image align bottom to image view with half size of your circular image. In my case circular image's height is 100 so, it's half is 50. Please see following image for detail.

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: Why not just use `centerYAnchor` instead of `bottomAnchor` + `contant`?

Comment: how to use centerYAnchor in storyboard?

Comment: The same way you used `centerXAnchor`?

Comment: Oh yeah ... I just tried, that's the another way. Thx!

Comment: That is the best way when you do not know the size of the `imageView`. In your way, you would need to calculate the padding based on the size of the `imageView`.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks guys i made it working combining both of yours solution.

Answer (score 2):

you should give center vertical constraint and then open constraint property  and change first item or second item (as per your requirement)  center y to top option  Like 
 [image]